# Using a php function using a variable with delimiters

Tags: php, function, variables, delimiter

I would like to know If I can use a php function on a variable that contains delimiters like `'` or `"`. I'm receiving a text content from my database and I would like to use: `strip_tags($desc);` on it but it does not work.

Here is an example of what it can contain using var dump:

```
string(1039) ""txt <a href=""/txt.php"" class=""txt"">txt</a> . txt'txt <a href=""/txt.php"" class=""txt"">txt</a> txtxtxtxt& " "
```

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? You should clarify it better. Please post the exact code, a text example, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead...

Comment: In the text I have stored in my db contains ' and " characters. When I apply strip_tags on a text where they are all preceded by backslashs the function works. When I try to use it directly on the text coming from the database it doesn't remove any html tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to remove all tags. You should use the builtin function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead.

Comment: I have tried too but it's only working when I try it on a variable with backslashs before the apostrophes. When I apply it directly on the content of the db it keeps displaying the html tags.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the string contains any quotes, so the error must be somewhere else. Could you post the input to strip_tags and its output, both using var_dump()?

Comment: Well never mind I guess thats not possible, and the answer is "it's retarded to have html code in a database"

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use ereg_replace as it is going to be discontinued.

**[ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php)**

*This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 6.0.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.*

**[strip_tags](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

That said do you want to change all those chars to empty or are you trying to strip the tags? You can also convert the chars to the [html_entities](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$desc = strip_tags($desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to work on the variable, not strip out the tags, then use this:

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

htmlentities, will make your ' & " safe to handle, then you can convert them back after if needed.

Reference for code: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php